# Recover list of tests in test runner in RubyMine

Tags: rubymine

Somehow the list of tests on the left pane of the test runner in RubyMine went away. Any ideas how to re-activate it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

J. Pablo,

Please check that Test::Unit test framework reporter is enabled in your rake task run configuration settings (RubyMine | Run | Edit Configurations | Rake | your_rake_task).

Answer (score 0):

Try the 'Layout'->'Restore Layout' action on the test-runner toolbar. This should help.